# Parsing 学校を休んで遊んでいるところを友達のお母さんに見られた。

Tags: grammar

I don't understand the following sentence from my textbook:

> 学校を休んで遊んでいるところを友達のお母さんに見られた。

I think this sentence means

> Mom saw us while we were playing hooky from school.

I don't understand why を is used after ところ instead of に, で, or が.
I think を marks the direct object, 学校を休んで遊んでいるところ, of 見られた.
I don't understand why the passive verb 見られた would have a direct objet.

- What does this sentence mean?
- Why is ところ followed by を, and what is its meaning?
- If を marks the direct object of 見られた, why does it have a direct object?

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to parse it? What parts do you understand? Have you tried translating it yourself and if you have, what is your best guess? Show us what  you know. This will also help in answering the parts you are confused about if we know your thought process.

Comment: Edited. Is it more clear?

Comment: You just should change it to passive form.

Comment: This is a sentence from my textbook that I'm trying to understand as-is. It was not an attempt by me to express anything.

Comment: I mean your translation just should change to passive form.

Comment: 間接受身(Indirect Passive) じゃないんですかね・・ 「私**は**泥棒**に**財布**を**盗まれた」みたいな。。

Answer (score 1):

It would be translated as "I was seen by my friend's mother to be playing hooky from school".

This ところ means "scene". You can remember this sentence "I was seen to break the window" and it is translated 私は窓を割るのを見られた. It can be rephrased as  私は窓を割るところを見られた.